# Boost 1.36 with STLPort 4.6.2 compilation error

Tags: c++, boost, stlport

I am trying to build Boost 1.36 with STLPort 4.6.2 on solaris, but getting below error,

```
 "CC" -fast -mt -KPIC -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_MATH_TR1_DYN_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG -D_STLP_USE_DYNAMIC_LIB=1 -I"." -I"/sw/source/mer_misc_libs/STLport-4.6.2" -c -o "bin.v2/libs/math/build/sun/release/stdlib-stlport-4.6.2/threading-multi/tgamma.o" "libs/math/build/../src/tr1/tgamma.cpp"

"./boost/array.hpp", line 75: **Error: Too few arguments for template std::reverse_iterator<boost::T*>.**
"./boost/array.hpp", line 295:     **Where: While specializing "boost::array<boost::T, boost::N>".**
"./boost/array.hpp", line 295:     **Where: Specialized in non-template code**.

"./boost/array.hpp", line 76: Error: Too few arguments for template std::reverse_iterator<const boost::T*>.
"./boost/array.hpp", line 295:     Where: While specializing "boost::array<boost::T, boost::N>".
"./boost/array.hpp", line 295:     Where: Specialized in non-template code.
2 Error(s) detected.
```

Please help in understanding the problem and how can I resolve ?

Is Boost supported for STLPort 4.6.2 ?

Command used to build:

`./tools/jam/src/bin.solaris/bjam --without-python stdlib=stlport-4.6.2 toolset=sun stage`

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below link for the answer, its a patch suggested on the boost.org site.

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/3893/boost-array.diff